# surfaceview create slowly and how to play

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to play some clips and use MediaPlayer with SurfaceView, but when I found SurfaceView create async , I must check `public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)` to verify , if not ,I can't play. How to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to resolve exactly. You have to have a drawing surface, so, if you want to use SurfaceView, you **have** to wait for the Surface to be created. Alternatively, you can use VideoView which takes care of the SurfaceView part for you. Or, depending what platform you are targeting, you can use TextureView instead of SurfaceView.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [AsyncTaskget()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29)!

It calls onPostExecute() after the execution is complete. Pass a reference to the SurfaceView you created in the AsyncTask. You'll get that reference in your java class.

Comment: in doInBackground and set a loop to check SurfaceView is completed?

Comment: Waiting for the surface to be created is already asynchronous. AsyncTask makes no sense here.